# Dynamics CRM Online 2016 Web API - Get user by Auzure AD Object ID

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2016, dynamics-crm-webapi

Is it possible to get a user object from Dynamics CRM Online 2016 Web API by the users ObjectID from AzureAD.

I am able to get a user by its `windowsliveid` (as in example below) but cannot find the GUID for the user that is shared between Azure AD and CRM Online.

```
/api/data/v8.1/systemusers?$filter=windowsliveid eq 'user.name@contoso.com'
```

Maybe this isn't even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `azureactivedirectoryobjectid` attribute of `systemuser` entity. [MSDN Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt608065.aspx)

The below code should work.

```
/api/data/v8.1/systemusers?$filter=azureactivedirectoryobjectid eq guid
```

Note: guid without single quotes